# Is there a general transformation for this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Consider the following:

$$
\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}^\text{T}\mathbf{B}
\tag{1}
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are $n\times m$ matrices. Is it possible to write this in the form

$$
\left(\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y}\right)^\text{T}\left(\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y}\right)
\tag{2}
$$
via some transformation? I.e

$$
\mathbf{X}^\text{T}\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y}^\text{T}\mathbf{Y}+\mathbf{X}^\text{T}\mathbf{Y}+\mathbf{Y}^\text{T}\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}^\text{T}\mathbf{B}
\tag{3}
$$

What I'm hoping to achieve is to preserve $\left(\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{Y}\right)$ as an $n\times m$ matrix. Rather than Cholesky decompose $\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}^\text{T}\mathbf{B}
$ directly and end up with an $m\times m$ matrix.

UPDATE: An attempt. Let

$$
\mathbf{A} = \pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\beta}\mathbf{X}
\tag{4}
$$
And
$$
\mathbf{B} = \pmb{\gamma}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\delta}\mathbf{X}
\tag{5}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A} & = \left( \pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\beta}\mathbf{X}\right)^\text{T}  \left( \pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\beta}\mathbf{X}\right) \\
& = \mathbf{Y}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y} +  \mathbf{X}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta}\mathbf{X} +  \mathbf{Y}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta}\mathbf{X}+ \mathbf{X}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}
\end{align}
\tag{6}
$$
Similarly:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}^\text{T}\mathbf{B} & = \left( \pmb{\gamma}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\delta}\mathbf{X}\right)^\text{T}  \left( \pmb{\gamma}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\delta}\mathbf{X}\right) \\
& = \mathbf{Y}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma}\mathbf{Y} +  \mathbf{X}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta}\mathbf{X} +  \mathbf{Y}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta}\mathbf{X}+ \mathbf{X}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma}\mathbf{Y}
\end{align}
\tag{7}
$$
Therefore

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}^\text{T}\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}^\text{T}\mathbf{B} & = \left( \pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\beta}\mathbf{X}\right)^\text{T}  \left( \pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\beta}\mathbf{X}\right) \\
& = \mathbf{Y}^\text{T}\left(\pmb{\alpha}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha}+\pmb{\gamma}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma}\right)\mathbf{Y} +  \mathbf{X}^\text{T}\left(\pmb{\beta}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta} + \pmb{\delta}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta}\right)\mathbf{X} +  \mathbf{Y}^\text{T}\left(\pmb{\alpha}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta}+\pmb{\gamma}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta}\right)\mathbf{X}+ \mathbf{X}^\text{T}\left(\pmb{\beta}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha} + \pmb{\delta}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma}\right)\mathbf{Y}
\tag{8}
\end{align}

Comparing this with eqn 2, then we have the following conditions:

\begin{align}
& \pmb{\alpha}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha}+\pmb{\gamma}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma} = \pmb{1}\\
& \pmb{\beta}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta} + \pmb{\delta}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta} = \pmb{1}\\
& \pmb{\alpha}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta}+\pmb{\gamma}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta} = \pmb{1}\\
& \pmb{\beta}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha} + \pmb{\delta}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma}= \pmb{1}\\
\tag{9}
\end{align}

From equation 4 we have that:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}
 = \pmb{\beta}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{A} - \pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}\right)
\tag{10}
\end{align}
Substituting into equation 5:

$$
\mathbf{B} = \pmb{\gamma}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{A} - \pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}\right)
\tag{11}
$$
Expanding:

$$
\mathbf{B} = \pmb{\gamma}\mathbf{Y}+\pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\mathbf{A} - \pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\pmb{\alpha}\mathbf{Y}
\tag{12}
$$
Writing in terms of $\mathbf{Y}$ we find that

$$
\mathbf{Y} = \left(\pmb{\gamma}- \pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\pmb{\alpha}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf{B}-\pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\right)
\tag{13}
$$
substituting into equation 10:

$$
\mathbf{X}
 = \pmb{\beta}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{A} - \pmb{\alpha}\left(\pmb{\gamma}- \pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\pmb{\alpha}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf{B}-\pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\right)\right)
\tag{14}
$$

And hence

$$
\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{Y} = \left(\pmb{\gamma}- \pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\pmb{\alpha}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf{B}-\pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\right) + \pmb{\beta}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{A} - \pmb{\alpha}\left(\pmb{\gamma}- \pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\pmb{\alpha}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathbf{B}-\pmb{\delta}\pmb{\beta}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\right)\right)
\tag{15}
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
& \pmb{\alpha}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha}+\pmb{\gamma}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma} = \pmb{1}\\
& \pmb{\beta}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta} + \pmb{\delta}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta} = \pmb{1}\\
& \pmb{\alpha}^\text{T}\pmb{\beta}+\pmb{\gamma}^\text{T}\pmb{\delta} = \pmb{1}\\
& \pmb{\beta}^\text{T}\pmb{\alpha} + \pmb{\delta}^\text{T}\pmb{\gamma}= \pmb{1}\\
\tag{16}
\end{align}
Is there a way to find these four matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your matrix $C=A^TA+B^TB$ is guaranteed to be a symmetric matrix (in fact positive definite as well). Note that the rank $r$ of your matrix obeys $r\leq \min(n,m)$. W.l.o.g assume $r=n$. You can write the eigen-decomposition as $$C=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i u_i u_i^T$$ where $u_i$ are the $m\times 1$ eigenvectors. Convince yourself that you can write this as $$C=\hat{U}\hat{\Sigma}\hat{U}^T$$ where $\hat{U}$ is the $m\times n$ matrix whose columns are the eigen-vectors and $\hat{\Sigma}$ is the $n \times n$ diagonal with the eigen values. Now, your requirement becomes straightforward. Define $R=\hat{U}\hat{\Sigma}^{1/2}$ so that $C=R^TR$ and $R$ is $n \times m$ matrix.

Comment: Many thanks dineshdileep for your answer. Yes I recognise this as an eigenvalue/SVD problem. The problem I have is that once I have $C$ it is square. Therefore trying to find the non-square solution for $R$ is surely impossible at that point as any decomposition; cholesky, QR, LU, SVD ect will return a square matrix. I specifically need the non-square solution and I was hoping that the above would go some way to obtaining that. Or am I missing something? Is it possible to find the non-square solution for $R$ via another decomposition of mathematical trick?

Comment: $C$ is square. Its SVD will also be square. But the point is, you can select the singular vectors from the SVD which correspond to only the non-zero singular values. Thus full SVD (square)  will become a thin-svd which will no longer be "square". Look up on thin-svd. Thoug I said eigendecompositon, since your matrix is square and symmetric, SVD would do the same job.